# Meteor table template not getting populated

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

One thing I will say is I am new to web developing and to meteor in particular so any help will be appreciated.

I have a web page where I have the user input 2 figures, use them as a variable once submitted by a button click. the 2 figures are used to calculate items in a JS object. When I check in the console once I submit the figures the object shows all the correct figures, however the html is not making it's way into the template.
I do have two other templates in the page and they are working fine. The table is also populating in the page but not filling in the values needed once the calculations are done.
I have put the code in Code Pen. Here is the [link](http://codepen.io/webventure/pen/YqKRBq). Below is the js code. I have included in codepen the HTML as well.

```
Template.input_fields.events({
    'click #inputForm': function (e) {


        console.log("clicked");
        // create variables for user FTP and LTHR values
        var ftp_value = $("#ftp").val();
        var lthr_value = $("#lthr").val();

        // Calculation of training zones for power and heart rate.
        var calculations = [

            {end_1: ftp_value * .56},
            {end_2: ftp_value * .75},
            {end_3: lthr_value * .80},
            {end_4: lthr_value * .90},
            {tempo_1: ftp_value * .76},
            {tempo_2: ftp_value * .85},
            {tempo_3: lthr_value * .91},
            {tempo_4: lthr_value * .95},
            {ss_1: ftp_value * .86},
            {ss_2: ftp_value * .95},
            {ss_3: lthr_value * .96},
            {ss_4: lthr_value * .99},
            {threshold_1: ftp_value * .96},
            {threshold_2: ftp_value * 1.05},
            {threshold_3: lthr_value * 1},
            {threshold_4: lthr_value * 1.02},
            {vo2_1: ftp_value * 1.06},
            {vo2_2: ftp_value * 1.20},
            {vo2_3: lthr_value * 1.03},
            {vo2_4: lthr_value * 1.06},
            {anaerobic_1: ftp_value * 1.21},
            {anaerobic_2: ftp_value * 1.50},
            {anaerobic_3: "Over"},
            {anaerobic_4: lthr_value * 1.06},
            {np_2: ftp_value * 1.51}

        ];

        console.log(calculations);
        Template.table.helpers({table: calculations});
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you've defined your `helpers` into the `events` won't work. because that's not the way meteor works. As of your case, you need to have a `reactive Dict` which will take your `calculations` value, and you'll return that `reactive Dict` in your helper to get the reactivity. you can have a global variable or template level variable. you need to have the reactive Dict package installed. if not , write on the command `meteor add reactive-dict`. and your code would be like this.

```
Template.input_fields.onCreated(function(){
    rd = new ReactiveDict('myDict');
    rd.set('calculations', []);
});

Template.input_fields.helpers({
    'table': function(){
         return rd.get('calculations'); // will return your array. when ever data changes, helper will change automatically.
    }
});

Template.input_fields.events({
    'click #inputForm': function(e) {
         ... your previous code here except last line. then
         rd.set('calculations',calculations);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining that. I see what I was doing wrong. Your suggestions make all the calculations correctly and I can see the values for 'rd' in the console. but I am still not getting those values in  HTML in the table. Is there something wrong with the way my template is set up possibly? I did get a lot from you answer, thank you. I've updated the code in codepen in case you want to look?

Comment: please show your template code, otherwise it's tough to tell why it's not working.

Comment: The code for the template is in the HTML section of the codepen link: (http://codepen.io/webventure/pen/YqKRBq)  I'm sure there is a more efficient way to lay this out but like I said I'm just getting started with meteor apps. Thanks.

Comment: please use `meteorpad` and share that link, otherwise i won't be able to find out the issue.

Comment: meteorpad.com seems to be down right now. Cannot reach the site. thanks but I will have to wait until it comes back up before posting a link here.